# How to use JSF navigation rules with ResourceBundle content

Tags: jsf, internationalization

I have a multi-lingual site with content managed by ResourceBundles. How can I use JSF navigation to insert links to website sections using paragraph content.

**Example 1: Desired HTML output**

```
<p>Simply <a href="contact.xhtml">contact us</a> to find out more.</p>
```

**Example 2: Simple facelt to achieve the above**

```
<p>Simply <h:link outcome="contact" value="contact us"/> to find out more.</p>
```

**Desired result: Same but with ResourceBundle**

Facelet

```
<p>
    <h:outputText value="${template['paragraph']}">
        <f:param>
            <h:link outcome="contact" value="${template['contactUs']}"/>
        </f:param>
    </h:outputText>
</p>
```

ResourceBundle

```
paragraph=Simply {0} to find out more.
contactUs=contact us
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not exactly the JSF navigation rules, but that you cannot use `<f:param>` to specify JSF components as bundle parameter, let alone plain vanilla HTML children. Also, please note that you cannot use `<f:param>` in `<h:outputText>`, but only in `<h:outputFormat>`.

In order to achieve the functional requirement anyway, you've to write down the HTML in escaped flavor as `<f:param value>` yourself.

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{template['paragraph']}" escape="false">
    <f:param value="&lt;a href='#{request.contextPath}/contact.xhtml'&gt;#{template['contactUs']}&lt;/a&gt;" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

or, if you'd like to utilize JSF `ViewHandler#getBookmarkableURL()` like as `<h:link>` is doing for its `outcome` attribute,

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{template['paragraph']}" escape="false">
    <f:param value="&lt;a href='#{facesContext.application.viewHandler.getBookmarkableURL(facesContext, '/contact', null, false)}'&gt;#{template['contactUs']}&lt;/a&gt;" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

Since you're not the first one who stumbled upon this and the workarounds are awkward, the JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has recently updated its `<o:param>` component with support to encode children as param value when no value is specified. From OmniFaces 1.5 on, you should be able to use it as follows:

```
<h:outputFormat value="#{template['paragraph']}" escape="false">
    <o:param><h:link outcome="contact" value="#{template['contactUs']}" /></o:param>
</h:outputFormat>
```

Comment: Excactly what I needed, thanks BalusC! It would even get more uglier if query parameters would be needed with linked converters.