# Passing HTML into message bundle

Tags: jsf, internationalization, seam, jsf-1.2

I am in the process of 'Internationalising' my App, which is SEAM 2 / JSF 1.2 based

One thing that is annoying me is having HTML markup in the message bundle, I would like to avoid this if possible, say for example I have the following HTML

```
<p>Click <span class="link" id="trigCl">here</span> to register your account.</p>
```

I wanted to break this down into the following:

```
<h:outputFormat escape="false" value="#{messages['registerAccountText']}">
    <f:param value="<span class='link' id='trigCl'>#{messages['here']}</span>" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

With the following bundle entry:

```
registerAccountText=Click {0} to register your account.
```

But as you guessed, I get the following...

```
The value of attribute "value" associated with an element type "f:param" must not contain the '<' character.
```

Is there a) a way to get around this, or b) a better way to go about this (which doesnt involve completely re-writing the markup)?

Comment: Not sure if there is a better way here but it sounds like the perfect opportunity for developing a new component?

Comment: I was afraid someone would say that! Can you recommend any good resources / example I can use (JSF 1.2) to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15589583/how-to-use-jsf-navigation-rules-with-resourcebundle-content) answer to a similar question from the omni-present BalusC which demonstrates a way to escape the HTML in the f:param

```
<h:outputFormat escape="false" value="#{messages['registerAccountText']}">
    <f:param value="&lt;span class='link' id='trigCl'&gt;#{messages['here']}&lt;/span&gt;" />
</h:outputFormat>
```

Not exactly the cleanest solution but until I can move up to JSF 2.0 it will have to do